How can I set the maximum frame rate in Flutter Flame?
How can I set the maximum frame rate in Flutter Flame?
It seems that it's not mentioned in the documentation. I couldn't find it. Is it not possible to change it?
https://docs.flame-engine.org/main/index.html
Are you saying that since we get delta time, it's not really an issue?

Do you mean a max frame-rate, or a fixed frame-rate? And a side question; for what purpose do you need it?

@spydon I have little experience in game development, so I am trying to learn from various articles. It seems that in Pygame, you can change the frame rate using clock.tick(30). If the same thing can be done in Flame, it would make it easier for me to refer to Pygame articles.(I am still in the learning phase, so I won’t know if it will be helpful until I try it.)

@shingo-nakanishi if you're just getting started using Flame I would recommend not using a fixed frame rate, you only need that for very specific use-cases. And I would recommend following Flame tutorials instead of Pygame articles, on our discord there is a channel dedicated for links to tutorials and articles about Flame.

You usually don't want to do this, usually you want to build your code dependent on the delta time (dt) that you get in the update methods.
But if you really want to set a fixed update rate (not the same as frame rate, but it should most likely not matter for your use-case) you can override updateTree in your game class:
class MyGame extends FlameGame {
  var _dtSum = 0.0;
  final fixedRate = 1/60; // 60 updates per second

  @override
  void updateTree(double dt) {
    _dtSum += dt;
    if(_dtSum > fixedRate) {
      super.updateTree(fixedRate);
      _dtSum -= fixedRate;
    }
  }
}


This is the same concept as already answered: https://stackoverflow.com/a/79089117/1979953
I have created an example where only a specific component subtree runs at 60 FPS, while another component subtree runs at 30 FPS.
Using a stopwatch, I observed that at around 10 seconds, the component placed on the left (aPositionComponent) indicated approximately 600, while the component placed on the right (bPositionComponent) indicated approximately 300.
Note:

You usually don't want to do this, usually you want to build your code dependent on the delta time (dt) that you get in the update methods.

References:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/79089117/1979953
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/212544/what-factors-determine-the-frame-rate-in-game-programming

import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flame/components.dart';
import 'package:flame/game.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const FooApp());
}

class FooApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const FooApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: GameWidget.controlled(gameFactory: FooFlameGame.new),
    );
  }
}

class FooFlameGame extends FlameGame {
  final aPositionComponent = APositionComponent();
  final bPositionComponent = BPositionComponent();
  final stopwatchTextComponent = TextComponent();

  final stopwatch = Stopwatch();

  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    super.onLoad();

    debugMode = true;
    stopwatch.start();

    await add(FpsTextComponent());
    await add(stopwatchTextComponent..position = Vector2(300, 0));

    await add(aPositionComponent);

    bPositionComponent.position = Vector2(500, 0);
    await add(bPositionComponent);
  }

  @override
  void update(double dt) {
    super.update(dt);

    stopwatchTextComponent.text = "stopwatch: ${stopwatch.elapsed}";
  }
}

class APositionComponent extends PositionComponent with HasGameReference<FooFlameGame>, HasVisibility {
  APositionComponent() : super();

  var _dtSum = 0.0;
  final fixedRate = 1 / 60; // 60 updates per second

  final debugTextPositionComponent = DebugTextPositionComponent();

  @override
  void updateTree(double dt) {
    _dtSum += dt;
    if (_dtSum > fixedRate) {
      super.updateTree(fixedRate);
      _dtSum -= fixedRate;
    }
  }

  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    super.onLoad();

    await add(debugTextPositionComponent);
  }
}

class BPositionComponent extends PositionComponent with HasGameReference<FooFlameGame>, HasVisibility {
  BPositionComponent() : super();

  var _dtSum = 0.0;
  final fixedRate = 1 / 30; // 30 updates per second

  final debugTextPositionComponent = DebugTextPositionComponent();

  @override
  void updateTree(double dt) {
    _dtSum += dt;
    if (_dtSum > fixedRate) {
      super.updateTree(fixedRate);
      _dtSum -= fixedRate;
    }
  }

  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    super.onLoad();

    await add(debugTextPositionComponent);
  }
}

class DebugTextPositionComponent extends PositionComponent
    with HasGameReference<FooFlameGame>, HasVisibility {
  DebugTextPositionComponent() : super();

  final dtTextComponent = TextComponent();
  final dtToFpsTextComponent = TextComponent();
  final countUpPositionComponent = CountUpPositionComponent();

  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    super.onLoad();

    dtTextComponent.position = Vector2(50, 100);
    dtToFpsTextComponent.position = Vector2(50, 200);
    countUpPositionComponent.position = Vector2(50, 250);
    await add(dtTextComponent);
    await add(dtToFpsTextComponent);
    await add(countUpPositionComponent);
  }

  @override
  void update(double dt) {
    super.update(dt);

    dtTextComponent.text = "dt: $dt";

    final fpsFromDt = 1 / dt;
    dtToFpsTextComponent.text = "fps from dt: $fpsFromDt";
  }
}

class CountUpPositionComponent extends PositionComponent with HasGameReference<FooFlameGame>, HasVisibility {
  CountUpPositionComponent() : super();

  var i = 0;
  final countUpPositionComponent = TextComponent();

  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    super.onLoad();

    await add(countUpPositionComponent);
  }

  @override
  void update(double dt) {
    super.update(dt);

    countUpPositionComponent.text = "i: $i";
    i++;
  }
}

